# as3 - movieclip flickers when flipping it horizontally?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I move my cursor, the player flips from left to right as expected. However, when I keep my cursor still in the middle of the screen (not moving cursor but, instead the player using "WASD" keys), and make my player move towards the cursor and walk past it. Then the player will change scale to horizontal. However, just before it changes scale, the children (player's arms, turret) inside the player flickers to scaleY before changing horizontal scale.

This is my code located inside the container of the player, it's the "PageOne" class.

```
if (mouseX > player.x)
        {

            player.playerStand.scaleX = 1;
            player.turret.scaleY = 1;
            player.armBottom.scaleY = 1;
            player.armTop.scaleY = 1;
            crosshair.x = mouseX;

        }
        else if (mouseX < player.x)
        {

            player.playerStand.scaleX = -1;
            player.turret.scaleY = -1;
            player.armBottom.scaleY = -1;
            player.armTop.scaleY = -1;
            crosshair.x = mouseX;
        }
```

So, I am trying to make it so the player's children do not flicker before flipping horizontally and instead instantly change horizontal shape. The movieclip that has ScaleX does not flicker, but the children that use scaleY has this flickering issue. It may be a bit hard to understand by reading so I added a file below.

Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lf17oj29iuk761/Subject%20Unstable.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is not caused by `scaleY` properties. It is caused by the rotation conditions inside `Player` class. Follow the next steps:

First of all delete the `scaleY` properties on `pageOne` class:

```
private function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void
{
    crosshair.x += (mouseX - crosshair.x) / 5;
    crosshair.y += (mouseY - crosshair.y) / 5;

    player.scaleX = (mouseX > player.x) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Next, you need to fix the rotation angle of the turret on the `Player` class:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI * 180;

if(armBottom.parent.scaleX < 0) angle = 180 - angle;
```

Next delete all rotations conditions and only left the elements rotations:

```
if (armBottom.currentFrame != 3)
{
    armBottom.rotation = angle;
}

if (armTop.currentFrame != 3)
{
    armTop.rotation = angle;
}

turret.rotation = angle;
```

You will note that the flickering is not produced, but now will not be a limit to the arms rotations.

You must check the angle value instead of check the rotation of the elements, it will be more easy and more clean:

```
if(armBottom.parent.scaleX < 0) angle = 180 - angle;

// Limit the rotation between -30º and 30
// If you want other values change this part.
if(armBottom.parent.scaleX > 0)
{

    if(angle >= -180 && angle < -30) angle = -30;
    if(angle > 30 && angle <= 180 ) angle = 30;

}
else
{

    if(angle < 330 && angle >= 180) angle = 330;
    if(angle > 30 && angle < 180) angle = 30;

}    

if (armBottom.currentFrame != 3)
{
    armBottom.rotation = angle;
    armTop.rotation = angle;
}               

turret.rotation = angle;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it by keeping the rotation restrictions?